# Regex matching a percentage of tokens - possible?

Tags: regex, delphi

I am working of a type of fuzzy match program.  I have a series of tokens I am matching.  (Program is written in Delphi XE6 if that makes any difference).

I would like to match against a set of token, but a percentage of the tokens.
For example, I have a regex expression searching for the tokens 'one, two' and 'three'.  This REQUIRES all three tokens.  Is there a way to build a Regex Expression which says match a minimum 50% of the token?  I know I can say 'Match any token', then do Substring checking and math...

Here is my Regex expression.

```
^(?=.*?\bone)(?=.*?\btwo)(?=.*?\bthree).*$
```

As an example.. IN PSEUDO-CODE...  I am looking for something like...

```
 ^[MATCH=50%MIN](?=.*?\bone)(?=.*?\btwo)(?=.*?\bthree).*$
```

since I have 3 tokens, \bone, \btwo, and \bthree, matching at least 50% of these tokens means that I have to match 2 out of the three, so

```
one four three = MATCHED
```

whereas

```
one four five = NOT MATCHED
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is meant for matching or not matching, there are no calculation functions in the library. You can look for partial matches, so you can look for a combination of one, four, and not five - but you would have to create regex's for each of those scenarios.

To solve this problem you will more than likely have to look for each thing and do a calculation to see if it's greater than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done, at least in your example, by making a simple quantification constraint, 2-or-greater:

```
(.*\b(one|two|three)\b){2,}
```

It can't be a **computed** 50%, but if you know how many tokens you're trying to match, then you know where the cutoff is...

Duplicates will also count in the above case: `one four one = MATCH`. If there can be duplicates in the target and you only want to match if a majority of the "source" tokens were matched, you'd need the equivalent of the following in perl:

```
/\bone\b/ + /\btwo\b/ + /\bthree\b/ >= 2
```